# Set input with datepicker to any string in AngularJS 1.5.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-1.5

this may be a simple question, but I have looked and cannot find my answer...

I have an input box with an [Angular-UI Bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!datepickerPopup):

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    id="id" name="id"
    uib-datepicker-popup="MMddyyyy" ng-model="date" 
    is-open="isDatePickerOpen" 
    close-text="Close" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openFrom($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
</span>
```

This works fine for selecting dates.  I can also enter free-form text, but it only binds properly when I enter a date in the format specified.  If I enter something else like 'abcd', it binds to undefined.  I suspect the datepicker itself is putting restrictions on what is allowed in the input box, but not sure how to remove those restrictions.  I am open to using any datepicker that is supported by most browsers.

Comment: What does `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` return with invalid dates?

Comment: @georgeawg adding that to my input tag still results in undefined for 'abcd'

Comment: In my experience it is not worth the effort to fight these libraries. The HTML5 date picker has a stricter format and makes it difficult to enter invalid dates. When the date is invalid it returns `""`, `null`, and `NaN` for `value`, `valueAsDate`, and `valueAsNumber` respectively. It never returns the actual invalid text. With the `uib-datepicker`, you could write a directive that returns the actual text because under-the-hood it uses `<input type="text">`.

Comment: When using online tools, I can get it to work exactly how I want using `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"`, but I copied and pasted that code directly into my code and it no longer works.  Wonder if its a version issue or something else is overriding it.  I will probably just have to accept this limitation and find another solution.  I initially thought this would be fairly easy as you mention it is a text input box and not a date.  Thanks for your help.